# C++ Call external function from class

Tags: c++, arduino

I have two classes:

```
class class1 {

   private:
      void (*readSerial)(void) = NULL;
            
   public:
      class1(void (*handler)(void));

};

class class2 {

   private:
      class1 c1 = NULL;
            
   public:
      
      void readSerialData() {}

      class2() {
        this->c1 = class1(this->readSerialData());
      }
};
```

But show me one error: *invalid use of void expression* in this line: *this->c1 = class1(this->readSerialData())*

Any idea?

Regards

Comment: A pointer to a non-member function (like `class1::readSerial`) is *not* the same as a pointer to a member function (like `&class2::readSerialData`). Also, you *call* the `readSerialData` function, not passing a pointer.

Comment: Furthermore, `NULL` is an old C compatibility macro for null *pointers*. C++ doesn't have "null values".

Comment: Can you explain why chose this approach? Can't you pass a reference to the `class2` instance instead and have `class1` call `ref.readSerialData()`? If not, have you considered passing an `std::function`?

Comment: Possibly: -> `static void readSerialData() {}`, -> `class2() : c1(&class2::readSerialData) {}`.
      }

Answer (score 1):

This is how your code can be made to compile without errors:

```
class class2;
class class1 {

   private:
      void (class2::*readSerial)(void);
            
   public:
      class1(void (class2::*)(void));

};

class class2 {

   private:
      class1 c1;            
   public:      
      void readSerialData() {}
      class2() : c1(&class2::readSerialData) {}
};
```

Free function pointers are fundamentally different from member function pointers: You need an object to call them. An object cannot be `NULL`. `NULL` should be avoided altogether in favor of `nullptr`. For initialization of members you should use the member initializer list rather than assignment in the constructor body.

However, this wont help you to call `class2::readSerialData` from `class1`, because you need an object of `class2` to call one of its methods. It's not quite clear why you started with function pointers, so I cannot tell you how to fix your actual issue, but this works (and is much simpler):

```
class foo {
   public:      
      void readSerialData() {}
};

class bar {
   private:
      foo f;          
   public:
      void readSerial() {
          f.readSerialData();
      }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`readSerialData` returns `void`, so you can't use its return value at all - because there's none.

With `class1(this->readSerialData())` you are constructing an object of type `class1` using a `void` parameter - which is not legal.

Also, `class1 c1 = NULL;` is very confusing - that invocation is just converting NULL (which is an alias for nullptr) to class1 by implicitly invoking `class1(void (*handler)(void))`, which is not what people expect when reading an assignment to NULL¹

Your specific example can be solved efficiently by using virtual functions and inheritance. It's basically as performant as using function pointers, without the caveats.

¹: try not using NULL in modern C++, and prefer to it the `nullptr` keyword when possible.